# Why Oracle live sql executes and prints one line multiple times?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run SQL on Oracle live and I give only one input but the output is printed multiple times, I don't know why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: You likely have insered the record 2 times.  Drop the table first and then give it another try.

Comment: ok so this really workedthank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL state is maintained between runs.

The first time you execute the script, it creates the table and inserts a row into the table and then you select the single row.

The second time you execute the script, it tries to create the table but finds that it already exists and raises an `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object` exception and then will insert the row into the table (so you now will have two rows in the table) and then you select both rows.

If you were to run it again, it will fail to create the table again, insert another row and show you three rows... and so on.

Instead of re-running the entire script (or adding `DROP TABLE` statements in), what you can do is delete the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements after they have been run the first time and just edit the `SELECT` statement to give the output you want.

If you want to see the entire history for the session then click on the "Actions" button and then "View Session".

If you want to drop all the changes and re-run the script from the beginning then use "Actions" then "Reset Session".

Answer (score 1):

You have executed it two times. First  time table has been created and a row has been inserted.
Second time table creation failed but a row has been inserted again.

And your select query is correctly showing both rows.

Drop the table and execute the query again.